# How to read and write to controls or settings with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am copying the string values out of text boxes on a form and saving them in the settings. The way I am doing it here seems kind of long handed. Is there a way to reference the TextBox1.Text and the My.Settings.Value1 with a string. If so then I could just loop through and keep changing the strings to point at the different controls. See the way I am currently doing it.

```
My.Settings.F1LabelCol0Save = F1LabelCol0.Text
My.Settings.F1LabelCol1Save = F1LabelCol1.Text
My.Settings.F1LabelCol2Save = F1LabelCol2.Text
My.Settings.F1LabelCol3Save = F1LabelCol3.Text
My.Settings.F1LabelCol4Save = F1LabelCol4.Text
My.Settings.F1LabelCol5Save = F1LabelCol5.Text
My.Settings.F1LabelCol6Save = F1LabelCol6.Text
My.Settings.F1LabelCol7Save = F1LabelCol7.Text
My.Settings.F1LabelCol8Save = F1LabelCol8.Text
My.Settings.F1LabelCol9Save = F1LabelCol9.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and here is how to do it. Now obviously it needs to be a number of of them very similarly named to to be worth it.

```
For i = 0 To 39
        My.Settings("F1LabelCol" & i.ToString & "Save") = Me.Controls("F1LabelCol" & i.ToString).Text
Next
```

Comment: The reason I couldn't get this to work right away was another issue that blind sided me.

Comment: The `.Text` should not be a part of the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can access both settings and controls dynamically via [**`My.Settings.Item()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.item.aspx) and [**`Me.Controls.Item()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1865435(v=vs.110).aspx).

I present you with two options:

**1)** Use a [**`For` loop**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) for a fixed number range:

```
For x = 0 To 9
    My.Settings("F1LabelCol" & x & "Save") = Me.Controls("F1LabelCol" & x).Text
Next
```

- **Upside:** Does not swallow exceptions (see next example).
- **Downside:** You must change the upper bound (currently 9) when you add new settings/controls.

**2)** Use a [**`While` loop**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx) for a dynamic number range.

```
Dim x As Integer = 0
While True
    Try
        My.Settings("F1LabelCol" & x & "Save") = Me.Controls("F1LabelCol" & x).Text
    Catch
        Exit While 'If an exception is thrown we've most likely hit the setting/control limit.
    End Try
End While
```

- **Upside:** Dynamic number range, you do not need to change anything when adding new settings/controls.
- **Downside:** Swallows exceptions, i.e. you won't know when an exception is thrown for another reason than when a setting/control does not exist.

---

If you want to load data dynamically as well just reverse the get/set operation:

```
Me.Controls("F1LabelCol" & x).Text = My.Settings("F1LabelCol" & x & "Save")
```